# Why cant my verilog testbench display intermediate variables?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl, test-bench

I want to see what value is stored in a1 and b1 but I get only "xxxxxx" as output. Why?

My code is designed to take values of a and b which are 4 bit signed numbers. I am using intermediate variables a1 and b1 to make 2's complement of those numbers if the MSB of a or b is 1 otherwise use the same a and b for my main code. But I am not able to get the intermediate values.

Relevant code and testbench;

```
module xx(a,b,z);
    input   signed [3:0] a,b;
    output  signed [7:0] z;
    integer i;
    wire w1,w2,w3,w4,w5,w6,w7,w8,w9,w10,w11,w12;    
    reg [3:0] pp0,pp1,pp2,pp3;
    reg [3:0] a1,b1;

   always @ (a or b)  begin  
      if ( a[3] == 1 && b[3] == 1) begin
          a1 <= ~a + 1;
          b1 <= ~b + 1;
      end else if ( a[3] == 1 && b[3] == 0) begin
          a1 <= ~a + 1;
          b1 <=b;
      end else if ( a[3] == 0 && b[3] == 1) begin
          a1 <= a;
          b1 <= ~b + 1;
      end else begin
          a1 <= a;
          b1 <= b;
      end
   end
.....
endmodule
```

Testbench

```
module xxt();
    reg  signed [3:0]a,b;
    wire  signed [7:0]z;
    reg [3:0] a1,b1; 

    xx w1(a,b,z);

    integer i;
    integer j;

    initial
    begin
        for ( i = 0; i<16; i = i + 1)
        begin
            for ( j = 16; j>0; j = j - 1)
            begin
                #10 b=j; a=i;
                //$display("a*b=z %d %d %d", a, b, z);
                //$display("a*b=z %b %b %b", a, b, z);
                $display("%t\ta\tb\ta1\tb1\tz\n\t\t%b\t%b\t%b\t%b\t%b", $time, a, b, a1, b1, z);
                $display("%t\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d", $time, a, b, a1, b1, z);
            end
        end
    end


endmodule
```

My transcript displays only this

```
 10 a   b   a1  b1  z
#       0000    0000    xxxx    xxxx    xxxxxxxx
#                   10    0   0  x   x     x
#                   20  a   b   a1  b1  z
#       0000    1111    xxxx    xxxx    xxxxxxxx
#                   20    0  -1  x   x     x
#                   30  a   b   a1  b1  z
#       0000    1110    xxxx    xxxx    00000000
#                   30    0  -2  x   x     0
#                   40  a   b   a1  b1  z
#       0000    1101    xxxx    xxxx    00000000
#                   40    0  -3  x   x     0
#                   50  a   b   a1  b1  z
#       0000    1100    xxxx    xxxx    00000000
#                   50    0  -4  x   x     0
#                   60  a   b   a1  b1  z
#       0000    1011    xxxx    xxxx    00000000
#                   60    0  -5  x   x     0
#                   70  a   b   a1  b1  z
#       0000    1010    xxxx    xxxx    00000000
#                   70    0  -6  x   x     0
#                   80  a   b   a1  b1  z
#       0000    1001    xxxx    xxxx    00000000
#                   80    0  -7  x   x     0
#                   90  a   b   a1  b1  z
#       0000    1000    xxxx    xxxx    00000000
#                   90    0  -8  x   x     0
#                  100  a   b   a1  b1  z
#       0000    0111    xxxx    xxxx    00000000
#                  100    0   7  x   x     0
#                  110  a   b   a1  b1  z
#       0000    0110    xxxx    xxxx    00000000
#                  110    0   6  x   x     0
#                  120  a   b   a1  b1  z
#       0000    0101    xxxx    xxxx    00000000
#                  120    0   5  x   x     0
#                  130  a   b   a1  b1  z
#       0000    0100    xxxx    xxxx    00000000
#                  130    0   4  x   x     0
#                  140  a   b   a1  b1  z
#       0000    0011    xxxx    xxxx    00000000
#                  140    0   3  x   x     0
#                  150  a   b   a1  b1  z
#       0000    0010    xxxx    xxxx    00000000
#                  150    0   2  x   x     0
#                  160  a   b   a1  b1  z
#       0000    0001    xxxx    xxxx    00000000
#                  160    0   1  x   x     0
....

and so on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of your testbench variables and the module are different. You need `xx.a1`, and no declaration of a1, b1 at the testbench level.

You'd also be better off with a more generic 'always', and a case statement (but those are style/performance/defensive, and won't affect the end result).

Comment: Thanks. My issue was soled by adding w1 before a1 and b1. '$display("%t\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d", $time, a, b, w1.a1, w1.b1, z);'  But still my 2's complement is wrong.

Comment: We're not here to debug your design... Try re-writing as a case statement, see if that makes it easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try to declare `a1` and `b1` as `logic`, and then initialize them.

Answer (score 0):

Because the a1,b1 you are displaying are the variable in your xxt test module and you don't do anything with them. The a1,b1 you are probably interested in are **local to (inside)** your xx module.

Also you are using non-blocking assignment throughout module xx where you should be using blocking ones. It works in simulation but a synthesis stool will complain.

Comment: Thanks. But how do I display my a1 and b1 in the transcript window or in a waveform?